# Charles App - command line to toggle macOS proxy

Tags: bash, macos, macos-sierra, charles-proxy

I am having issues with Charles App with browser-sync.
The only way I can get browser-sync to work is to toggle charles off reload a page and turn it back on to carry on working.

Charles has command line options.
Does anyone know the command to toggle the macOS proxy on and off? I want to able to automate this sort of thing

Thanks

Comment: I would add the "macOS" tag to the post, so macOS experts could help you in that, as you seem to settle for the macOS command line to toggle the proxy on an off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable or disable the **macOS proxy** in the Charles application, the application modifies the HTTP and HTTPS proxy configurations available on the **System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies** tab.

You can change these settings by using `networksetup` command. 
First, display the list of available network adapters:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

To configure and enable the localhost as HTTP and HTTPS proxies:

```
networksetup -setwebproxy "Wi-fi" 127.0.0.1 8888
networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Wi-fi" 127.0.0.1 8888
```

To disable the HTTP and HTTPS proxies:

```
networksetup -setwebproxystate "Wi-fi" off
networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "Wi-fi" off
```

To display proxy configurations:

```
networksetup -getwebproxy "Wi-Fi"
networksetup -getsecurewebproxy "Wi-Fi"
```

Check out the help for further options:

```
networksetup -help
```